# Communications link failure due to: java.io.EOFException

Tags: jdbc, tomcat5.5, communicationexception

My webapp is running on Tomcat 5.5, I declared the datasource in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/OrdiniWebDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

In context.xml (tomcat conf):

```
<Resource 
  auth="Container" 
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
  maxActive="100" 
  maxIdle="30" 
  maxWait="10000" 
  name="jdbc/OrdiniWebDS" 
  password="[mypassword]" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="jdbc:mysql://[myHost:port]/ordiniweb" 
  username="[myusername]"
 />
```

The database is a MySql 5.0.
Everything works well except that sometimes, after several hours of "unuse", at first access I got this Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1956)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2368)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2867)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1616)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1708)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3255)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1293)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1428)
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
 at com.blasetti.ordiniweb.dao.OrdiniDAO.caricaOrdine(OrdiniDAO.java:263)
...
** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2579)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2867)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1616)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1708)
 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3255)
 com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1293)
 com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1428)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
 com.blasetti.ordiniweb.dao.OrdiniDAO.caricaOrdine(OrdiniDAO.java:263)
...
```

I need to refresh and it works well again. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL drops unused connections after a while because it assumes that the other side forgot to close it.

What you need to do is to configure a check that Tomcat should apply before it reuses a pooled connection. To do this, add `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` to the end of the URL and add `validationQuery="Select 1"` to the `Resource` element:

```
<Resource 
  auth="Container" 
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
  maxActive="100" 
  maxIdle="30" 
  maxWait="10000" 
  name="jdbc/OrdiniWebDS" 
  password="[mypassword]" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="jdbc:mysql://[myHost:port]/ordiniweb?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" 
  username="[myusername]"
  validationQuery="Select 1"
 />
```

[EDIT] This page gives more details: [Configuring a MySQL Datasource in Apache Tomcat](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-apache-tomcat-1867.html)

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll try for sure. Reading the page you linked I think I don't need of 'useUnicode' and 'characterEncoding' params. Thanks, I'll update you.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your answer helped a lot, can you please also suggest how to do it in case of hibernate

Comment: @YashpalSingla: You will need to connect to your database using a connection pool like c3p0 or dbcp.

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks a ton! you sir have saved my day. I had similar problem with DBCP and Hibernate. autoReconnect=true saved me.

Comment: `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` ... Please note that if you want *real* UTF8 (which is [max. 4 bytes](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char/) instead of *mysql* 'UTF8' which is [max. 3 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) and can't encode all of Unicode) you would need to specify `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4`

Comment: @AaronDigulla, so wiull hibernate.autoReconnect =True work with c3p0.....i am also facing same issue my sql throws a communicate link error when it wake from sleep...i am using c3p0 driver