# Java Program throws java.io.EOFException just after starting the jar

Tags: java, mysql, eofexception

I have a jar which takes data from sql (in a loop) and puts into queue after processing it. It has been running well & good until today before started throwing `Communications link failure due to underlying exception:`. & the following continued . . .

> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.io.EOFException
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.io.EOFException  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1905)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2351)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2862)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:676)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1030)
>     at org.sun.Mailthread1.DataPush(Mailthread1.java:341)   at
>   org.sun.Mailthread1.run(Mailthread1.java:216)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **

From little googling I understand that this could be because of dead connection (because of longer inactivity). But in my situation the program is processing a couple of rows and then throwing this exception. Every time I restart the jar and the same happens.

How can I overcome this problem/exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4436997/2412209 Duplicate

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava pls note this. "Everything works well except that sometimes, after several hours of "unuse", at first access I got this Exception: ..... "